# iOS8 - Custom Keyboard Extension(Allow Full access)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios8-extension

I am working on keyboard extension app with iOS8.It is working fine.But for a while.I am having problem with Allow Full access(disable).Initially i have set All full access is "ON" in my device settings.Then i have no problems with keyboard extension.If i set  All full access to "OFF",keyboards not shown any more.Recently my app got rejected due to this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Hi, i want to know whether keywords typed by the user on custom keyboard can be accessed or saved in DB. Please guide if you have knowledge as i haven' got proper info about this after spending a lot of time searching and also i haven't worked on swift yet.

Answer (score 0):

If the AllowFullAccess is OFF, then your keyboard don't have access to shared folder